# How to plot svm model by using JRI?

Tags: java, r, jri

My r code as below:

```
svm_model <- ksvm(xtrain,ytrain,type="C-svc",kernel='vanilladot',C=1,scaled=c()) 
plot(svm_model,data=xtrain, xlab = "feature2", ylab="feature1")
```

I plot it with command:

```
re.eval("plot(svm_model,data=xtrain, xlab = \"feature2\", ylab=\"feature1\")");
```

It come out an empty graph. How can i plot this graph by using JRI in java?

Answer (score 0):

JRI is no different from R, so the regular R rules apply. What device are you using? (`JavaGD` is recommended for on-screen plots, but you can use other devices, too). Did you close the device to commit the file (for off-screen devices)? Did you load the necessary packages? Is your `plot` lattice-based and missing `print`? Please use [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) for help requests like that - given your lack of details it is may be more productive.

Comment: why necessary to use device? although i no use any device, i can plot graph too. For example i direct use command re.eval("plot(clist,err,type='l',xlab=\"C\",ylab=\"Error rate\")");      i also can plot a graph because clist and err is an array with 20 int values. I just unable to plot re.eval("plot(svm_model,data=xtrain, xlab = \"feature2\", ylab=\"feature1\")"); because svm_model not a values. Can you show me an simple example how to plot it ?